# I want to perform a word search with BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm developing with BigQuery, but I'm worried about performance and cost.
Could you please lend me your help?

**What I want to achieve**

Thanks for your message about
I want to search for words in English sentences such as
If I search for, I want to extract only information that includes for.
*Does not apply to fore, forever, etc.

1. Plan 1

```
`UNNEST(SPLIT(English, ' ')) AS word`
```

Split in SQL with then word = 'for' search

2. Plan 2
   Array the words in advance and store them in the DB column as an array type
   Use UNNEST to decompose the array type and then search for 'test'

Plan 1 is easy to implement, but I have concerns about performance.
There is a concern that plan 2 will increase the amount of data stored in the DB.

thank you.

Comment: For searching and filter rows, please use regular expression. `regexp_contains(text_column ||'.', r"for[^\w]") as flag_for_word,`   Do you need to search in advance? Do you know the words to search for?`How many are these?

Comment: I want to search based on the value entered by the user in a text box.
Therefore, I would like to be able to search even if symbols (.,?) are entered, such as [away.].

Comment: Please give more details, where does your user inputs the data? Looker Studio, your app? Again, using a regular expression to solve the task for each input seams the best solution.